# Pass three parameters to Prism DelegateCommand to use the same command on different button commands [MVVM mode]

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, delegatecommand

I have the following DelegateCommand, created with the Prism library.

```cs
public class AddressModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand MyButtonClickCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncToCall); }
    }

    public void FuncToCall(object context)
    {
        //this is called when the button is clicked
        Method1("string1", integer_number1);
    }
}
```

I have already bonded `MyButtonClickCommand` to a button in XAML file.

```xml
<Button Content="Click me" 
        Command="{Binding MyButtonClickCommand}"/>
```

But I would like to use the same `MyButtonClickCommand` for 2 more buttons instead of creating two additional DelegateCommands `MyButtonClickCommand1` & `MyButtonClickCommand2`.

So what I want is to add `string1` and `integer_number1` as parameters and call the same ICommand on different buttons like below

```xml
<Button Content="Click me" 
        Command="{Binding MyButtonClickCommand("string1", integer_number1)}"/>
```

```xml
<Button Content="Click me 2" 
        Command="{Binding MyButtonClickCommand("string2", integer_number2)}"/>
```

```xml
<Button Content="Click me 3" 
        Command="{Binding MyButtonClickCommand("string3", integer_number3)}"/>
```

Comment: You can pass a single object to the CommandParameter property of the Button, e.g. by a binding or by a direct assignment. That object is passed as argument to the command's Execute handler method.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your comment. But how the Execute handler will know that "string1" and integer_number1 where to be placed inside the ```FuncToCall()```?

Comment: @Clemens also I think that I cannot use more than 1 time the CommandParameter. Based on my question I have 2 parameters to pass in the DelegateCommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an instance of any class that could be declared in XAML

```
public class MyCommandParameter
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

to the `CommandParameter` property of a Button:

```
<Button Content="Click me" Command="{Binding ...}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <local:MyCommandParameter MyInt="2" MyString="Hello"/>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

The MyCommandParameter instance is passed to the Execute handler method's argument:

```
public void FuncToCall(object parameter)
{
    var param = (MyCommandParameter)parameter;

    // do something with param.MyInt and param.MyString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CommandParameter` property:

```
<Button Content="Click me 2" 
        Command="{Binding MyButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="2" />
```

You could then cast the `context` parameter to whatever the value of the command parameter is:

```
public void FuncToCall(object context)
{
    string parameter = context as string;
    if (int.TryParse(parameter, out int number))
    {
        //---
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mm8, although I need to pass two different parameters (i.e "string2" and integer_number2) at the same time. I think I cant use CommandParameter more than once.

Comment: So like a list guess?

Comment: Like a class with two properties. See the other answer for an example.

Comment: Ok let me try to create a class with two parameters and pass the class to ```object context```. I am happy that my question was clear at least :)

Comment: @DelusionX: See the other answer for an example.